# How to programmatically start OSGi

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I'm trying to start OSGi in Java as follows:

```
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;
import org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.Framework;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class Launcher {

    private static String[] libs = null;

    private BundleContext context;

    private Launcher() {

        FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();

        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
        config.put("osgi.console", "");
        config.put("osgi.clean", "true");
        config.put("osgi.noShutdown", "true");
        config.put("eclipse.ignoreApp", "true");
        config.put("osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel", "4");
        config.put("osgi.configuration.area", "./configuration");

        // automated bundles deployment
        config.put("felix.fileinstall.dir", "./dropins");
        config.put("felix.fileinstall.noInitialDelay", "true");
        config.put("felix.fileinstall.start.level", "4");

        Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);

        try {
            framework.start();
        } catch (BundleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();

        Bundle OSGiDmHelloWorldProvider = install("OSGiDmHelloWorldProvider");
        Bundle OSGiDmHelloWorldConsumer = install("OSGiDmHelloWorldConsumer");
        try {
            OSGiDmHelloWorldProvider.start();
            OSGiDmHelloWorldConsumer.start();
        } catch (BundleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Launcher();
    }

    private String[] getLibs() {
        if (libs == null) {
            List<String> jarsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            File pluginsDir = new File("libs");
            for (String jar : pluginsDir.list()) {
                jarsList.add(jar);
            }
            libs = jarsList.toArray(new String[jarsList.size()]);
        }
        return libs;
    }

    protected Bundle install(String name) {
        String found = null;

        for (String jar : getLibs()) {
            if (jar.startsWith(name + "_") || jar.startsWith(name + "-")) {
                found = String.format("file:libs/%s", jar);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("JAR for %s not found", name));
        }
        try {
            return context.installBundle(found);
        } catch (BundleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.sarxos</groupId>
    <artifactId>equinox-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>equinox-launcher</name>
    <description>Launcher for Equinox OSGi runtime</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-libs</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>libs</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:365)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at com.github.sarxos.equinox.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:21)
    at com.github.sarxos.equinox.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

What am I getting wron? What do I need to adjust to get it to work?

Comment: You need to put an OSGi framework implementation in your classpath.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSGi got FrameworkFactory could not be instantiated Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760795/osgi-got-frameworkfactory-could-not-be-instantiated-error)

Answer (score 4):

The error tells you that no FrameworkFactory could be found as you do not have a dependency to any OSGi framework. Add a dependency to equinox or felix in your pom and it should work.